# Checking stringstream line char by char C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, input, char, stack

I will keep it short and simple. After making sure that user is able to open a file succesfully, I have written the following piece of code to take a line from the inputFile.

```
string line;
int counter = 0;

DynIntStack stack;

while (!inputFile.eof())
{
    getline(inputFile, line);
    stringstream inputLine(line);
    counter++;

    //I NEED TO DO IT HERE
}
```

This will be used to write program to check balanced paranthesis in an input cpp file and I have to use stacks. Classic CS homework as I understand from the topics I have checked :)

counter is updated after every line and the line number(counter) is to be pushed to the stack if it has a opening bracket and it must be popped from the stack if it is a closing bracket. after these, the output should look something like this:

```
block: 3 - 3
block: 12 - 14
block: 10 - 14
block: 5 - 16
Syntax error in line 21.
```

But I do not know how to check the line I got char by char. I need a loop to check the chars and apply the previously mentioned things if an opening or closing bracket is found. How can I check the line char by char.

- using any data container other than stacks is forbidden.

thank you very much :)

Comment: Give some lines of your file

Comment: @KaidulIslam it can be any cpp file. you think of the simple ones like that includes int main and some functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But I do not know how to check the line I got char by char

Is this what you want?

```
string line;
int counter = 0;

DynIntStack stack;

while (getline(inputFile, line))
{
    counter++;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
        // line[i] is i'th character
        if(line[i] == '(') {
            // do stuff
        }
        else if(line[i] == ')') {
            // do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: note that first checking for eof and then reading data is the wrong way to do. Read data first and then check if the read failed.

Comment: Yes, I think `while(getline(inputFile, line)) { /*  */ }` should be okay

Comment: Any reason `i` isn't of type `size_t`? That would be preferred over the int cast, imho.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the correct answer by Kaidul Islam, a `std::string` support [range based for loops](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for).

```
string line;
int counter = 0;

DynIntStack stack;

while (getline(inputFile, line))
{
    ++counter;

    for (char const c : line)
    {
        if (c == '(')
        {
            // do stuff
        }
        else if (c == ')')
        {
            // do stuff
        }
    }
}
```